# Django How to reuse a URL and View based on an input or state?

Tags: django, django-urls

I currently have a url and a view to display my objects. Is it possible to create a new URL with the same view then just change the filter of objects without creating a new view?

This is my url:

```
path('search/', hrViews.hr_search, name='hr_search'), # Default
path('search/with_added_filter', hrViews.hr_search, name='hr_search'), # In here.
```

This is as simple as I can be.

default view:

```
def hr_search(request, *args, **kwargs):
    hrItems = ApplicantAccount.objects.get()
```

custom view that I want to render in the new url:

```
def hr_search(request, *args, **kwargs):
    hrItems = ApplicantAccount.objects.filter(...)
```

Comment: Can you show your views.py so that there is a clear idea about what object you want to render.

Comment: updated my question to add view.

Comment: the lower function will overwrite the upper function so you'll only have 1 function.

Answer (score 1):

For making generalized url for differnt filter values as well as handling url with no filter value, you can set your urls.py as--

```
path('search/', hrViews.hr_search, name='hr_search'),
path('search/<str:filter_name>/', hrViews.hr_search, name='hr_search') #here str denotes the datatype of passed value.
```

And define views.py as--

```
def hr_search(request, filter_name=default_filter_name):
    if(filter_name==default_filter_name):
        #do what you want when no filter value is passed
    else:
        hrItems = ApplicantAccount.objects.filter(field_name=filter_name)
```

Comment: if <str:filter_name> is blank, would it not affect the original view?

Comment: Updated the answer on how to handle the request if <str:filter_name> is blank.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my concern.